# What Characters need to be escaped in this below link in app.config file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

When I build the solution in .net, it shows error because of this link in app.config file. I think I need to escape some characters. Please suggest.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- For more information on using app.config transformation
     visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MarketSolutionUrl" 
         value="http://www.example.com/Search?sid=90&cid=329&lid=1033"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Which characters need to be escaped in the http link?

```
<add key="MarketSolutionUrl"
     value= "http://www.example.com/Search?sid=90&cid=329&lid=1033"/>
```

I tried `&=&amp` but it's still giving the error. Please advice.

Comment: & is not escaped as &amp... it should be &amp; (note the semicolon) but that shouldn't matter. What DOES matter is where you are using that value...

Comment: @TJMonk15: what makes you think an invalid XML doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
   <add key="MarketSolutionUrl"  value="http://www.example.com/Search?sid=90&amp;cid=329&amp;lid=1033"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Like in other XML you need to escape all five special characters

```
&     &amp;
"     &quot;
`     &apos;
<     &lt;
>     &gt;
```

Note your missing semicolon after `&amp`.

Comment: Escaping some of the characters in some cases is optional. `<a b='>"'/>` is valid XML.

Comment: @Athari: you're right. Do you still see XMLs of that style recently? I was hoping it was eliminated.

Comment: `new XDocument(new XElement("r", new XAttribute("a", "'\"<&>"), new XText("'\"<&>"))).ToString()` == `<r a="'&quot;&lt;&amp;&gt;">'"&lt;&amp;&gt;</r>` Surprise!